# Determine hbm2ddl value programmatically without triggering schema update

Tags: java, hibernate, hbm2ddl

I would like to know the value of the hbm2ddl feature during the runtime of my application. I succeeded to determine that value with the following code:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private getHbm2DdlValue() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = (LocalSessionFactoryBean) 
            applicationContext.getBean("&sessionFactory");
    Configuration conf = sessionFactoryBean.getConfiguration();
    String hbm2ddlValue = conf.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto");
    return hbm2ddlValue;
}
```

Now, I want to know that value **before** the automatic update is triggered. The problem with the solution above is, that retrieving the LocalSessionFactoryBean immediately triggers the automatic update.

I could read the configuration file from disk and interpret it - but I would rather like to let the configuration build by hibernate and then read the property from there.

Is there any other way to create or access the hibernate configuration without triggering the automatic schema update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to disable factory-initialization during `ApplicationContext` loading. The `LocalSessionFactoryBean` is a `FactoryBean`. Spring will call that object's `getObject()` method during initialization of the context and that will force the schema to be updated.

Note that the `Configuration` instance of the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` is configured and used directly in the `afterPropertiesSet()` method. You won't be able to intercept it either.

You'll need to create your own `Configuration` instance (or parse the file yourself) before the `ApplicationContext` is created. You can look at the source code of `LocalSessionFactoryBean` to see how that is done.